What's up with the homework tag?
I thought we had decided to avoid the homework tag, for all the reasons listed there.  In addition, the homework tag is a "meta tag", which are generally not a good idea on StackExchange sites.
Yet now that I look, I see that we have 59 questions tagged homework.  What's up with that?  And why is that OK?  OK, that latter was a rhetorical question: it seems pretty clear this is not desirable.
So, what shall we do about this?  Should we remove the homework tag from all of those questions, and delete the homework tag and agree to avoid its use in the future or add it to a tag blacklist?  Are we all agreed that this tag is inappropriate and should disappear?

I did a little research on blacklisting tags and found this. At least it is possible.

I updated the help center on-topic section about homework to make our expectations more explicit.

Something tells me this question could use an accepted answer since The homework tag has been blacklisted. ;)

One thing I don't like as homework has crept up is that now (and I am guilty of this too) we often ask "is this homework?". If we get rid of homework we should also stop this behavior too.
Instead, we should use the criteria Ninefingers suggested in the answer on the related question. 

The descriminant is whether the question is fundamentally well typed out and shows prior research/a clear problem, not whether it may or may not be an assignment. 

This is true whether or not the question is homework, so we really don't need to know. At that point, it doesn't matter if the OP's question is homework. 
The only problem I see with this stance is that sometimes questions are so easy that it is simpler for me to write out an answer than to comment "what research/work have you done", wait for them to update, then give an answer. So a lot of times I just write out the answer.
Anyways, I propose we:

Remove the homework tag from all questions
Ask SE to blacklist it
Stop asking people if their question is homework
Do a better job of requiring proof of some basic research so that the site doesn't turn into a question answering service


Sounds like a plan!  I like your analysis and proposed path forward.

I would like to revive this question and discussion. It's October/November and the beginning of semester, and the site is full of questions that are CLEARLY homework. What is wrong with marking this as homework? The site should not be about helping people with homework. Also, if someone has done research on a problem and has not succeeded: if it is for work or something they are studying and researching I think we should give them a full answer; if it is for homework then we should most certainly NOT give them a full answer. Homework that is assigned is intended to be done by the students and is at a level that the student is supposed to be able to solve themselves. So, even if they tried and failed, they shouldn't get a full answer here, and at most a hint. 
Not only do I think there should be a homework tag, I think we should have Crypto StackExchange and CryptoHomework StackExchange (just like there's a separate site for Cryptography Meta). However, a homework tase is a reasonable "compromise".

I share your concerns. When a site starts to get overwhelmed with "here's my homework exercise, solve it for me", I am concerned quality will go down and experts will participate less.  Both Math.SE and CS.SE have been struggling with similar issues, and what to do about them is controversial.  I'm not sure whether a homework tag is the right solution to the problem, though.

My take: we have no way to tell or enforce whether it is homework.  And it doesn't matter whether it is actually a homework exercise or just looks like one (i.e., just the statement of an exercise-style problem, with no progress shown and no motivation/context and no question other than "how do I solve it?" or "do my work for me").  Both are equally problematic.  I would suggest at least discouraging such questions (e.g., downvoting, possibly voting to close).  I'm not sure whether adding a homework tag to them makes them any better.

For comparison, here are how some other sites are grappling with this challenge.  CS.SE:  https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1151/755, https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755, https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/751/755.  Math.SE: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201/14578, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/14578, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14981/14578.  Physics.SE: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7407/24498, https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5179/24498, https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7162/24498.

Stats.SE: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1172/2921, https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4393/2921, https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5064/2921, https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2685/2921, https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2843/2921.

@D.W. I agree that we have no way of knowing. However, I believe that many will be honest and will mark it as homework. In these cases, I'll actually be happier to help and give a hint than someone who doesn't. There are no perfect solutions, but the current solution is bad.

@D.W. and @ Yehuda, mostly in reaction to this, I've created a new meta post which may be of interest to you.

@SEJPM, great idea, thank you!
